# Strange behavior when assigning values to a matrix (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, undefined-behavior

I am allocating three matrix (*matR*, *matG*, *matB*) using malloc and assigning to them some values of the vector *image*. 
As usual, i am using two integers (i, j) to make the loop for this job. In the first time, when i=0 and j=0, it assigns the following values: 197 to matR[0][0], 211 to matG[0][0] and 219 to matB[0][0]. Until now is OK. Those are the values that i want. But here comes the strange behavior: in some points new values are assigned to matR[0][0], matG[0][0], matB[0][0]!

This is the part of the code that is doing what i said:

```
int i, j, k;
std::vector<unsigned char> image; //the raw pixels
unsigned error = lodepng::decode(image, width, height, filename);

matR = (unsigned char**)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*width);
matG = (unsigned char**)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*width);
matB = (unsigned char**)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*width);

k=0;
for(i=0; i<width; i++) {
  matR[i] = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*height);
  matG[i] = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*height);
  matB[i] = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*height);

  for(j=0; j<height; j++) {
    matR[i][j] = image[k++];
    matG[i][j] = image[k++];
    matB[i][j] = image[k++];
    k++; //separator
}
```

I added some lines to debbug the code and, running on terminal, i got the following output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJuGx.jpg

*It shows that when i=100 and j=0, the value of matR[0][0] was changed to 176.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
matR = (unsigned char**)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*width);
```

should be:

```
matR = (unsigned char**)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char *)*width);
// Note here                                        ^
```

You are allocating room for `width` chars, not `width` pointers.  Oops.

However, given that you have tagged this with `c++` why don't you write:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> matR(width, std::vector<char>{height});
```

(There are better ways of writing a matrix class, but this is better than doing your own malloc.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on lines like this:

```
matR = (unsigned char**)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*width);
```

`matR` is an array of `unsigned char*` but you're only allocating it to be as big as an array of `unsigned char`. This will allocate 4 or 8 times less memory than is needed to actually store the pointers, causing the inner arrays you allocate to be pointed at incorrectly.